# Create toolbar of images for web app

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm building a very basic online application where you can take images from a toolbar (or some kind of storage box, since there will eventually be quite a few images) and drag and drop them onto a canvas. I'm new to web development, but I know how to do the drag and drop, I'm just looking for a way to make a toolbar and put images in it. Ideally, I'd like a box with a scrollbar.

This seems like it should be a pretty simple problem. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I ended up discovering was using

```
overflow: scroll;
```

in the CSS div containing the images.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very good and simple demonstration of the use of drag&drop in HTML5 :

http://html5demos.com/drag

Beware that it's easy to drag links (as in this demo) but it is not possible to drag any images that aren't inside links in IE9.

If you want a totally cross-browser solution, you'll have to revert to old solutions (track mouse down, move and up and set yourself the position of objects).

Comment: Can you tell me how to create a toolbar or scrollbar box to hold the images (not just a list)?

Comment: You just arrange your objects in an horizontal manner. But maybe you should look for an html+css tutorial first ? Maybe http://www.html.net/tutorials/css/ or http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/

Comment: Okay, so are you saying that there is no way to put them in a box with a scrollbar unless I write the javascript myself?

Answer (score 0):

If you say you know drag&drop and just want a box with a scroll bar then check this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/side-scroll.html